# Mean number of throws to exceed a threshold

Tags: distributions, mean, uniform-distribution, dice, sum

Say that you have a die with n faces, and you need to throw the die until the sum of your results exceeds a given threshold.

What is the average number of throws needed?

I think that to compute that average, you need the probability distribution of exceeding the threshold for a given number of throws, but I can't seem to find any "classical" distribution fitting that description...

Comment: The answer to this questions seems to also solve your question.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191193/calculating-the-expected-number-of-unbalanced-dice-needed-to-reach-a-sum